# No wlan0 interface : Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 16.04, broadcom

I installed b43-fwcutter & firmware-b43-installer on my ubuntu 16.04 (HP Pavilion G6 - 2149tx) laptop.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```

But I was unable to create wlan0 interface on my laptop.

```
ifconfig wlan0 up
wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
```

My configurations as follows:

```
iwconfig

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp7s0b1  IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"ISIS"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: EC:1D:7F:B6:17:58   
          Bit Rate=57.8 Mb/s   Tx-Power=19 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=68/70  Signal level=-42 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:37   Missed beacon:0

eno1      no wireless extensions.

enp0s20u2  no wireless extensions.

ifconfig

eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 84:34:97:7e:d3:80  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

enp0s20u2 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 36:4b:50:b7:ef:c2  
          inet addr:192.168.0.129  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::60df:e107:928f:791/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:833 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:874 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:162821 (162.8 KB)  TX bytes:113464 (113.4 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:472 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:472 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:34036 (34.0 KB)  TX bytes:34036 (34.0 KB)

wlp7s0b1  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 68:94:23:c9:1c:d8  
          inet addr:192.168.0.197  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::94f7:b2f:2512:b017/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:25 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:44 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2538 (2.5 KB)  TX bytes:7142 (7.1 KB)
```

And:

```
tree  /etc/modprobe.d/

/etc/modprobe.d/
├── alsa-base.conf
├── blacklist-ath_pci.conf
├── blacklist-bcm43.conf~
├── blacklist.conf
├── blacklist-firewire.conf
├── blacklist-framebuffer.conf
├── blacklist-modem.conf
├── blacklist-oss.conf -> /lib/linux-sound-base/noOSS.modprobe.conf
├── blacklist-rare-network.conf
├── blacklist-watchdog.conf
├── dkms.conf
├── fbdev-blacklist.conf
├── intel-microcode-blacklist.conf
├── iwlwifi.conf
├── mlx4.conf
└── vmwgfx-fbdev.conf


$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

$ dmesg | grep -i firmware
[    0.145271] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.315344] [Firmware Bug]: Invalid critical threshold (0)
[    2.426164] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[   13.536705] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for    brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e3.hcd failed with error -2
```

I need to setup wlan0 on my laptop. Thank You.

Comment: "I need to setup wlan0 on my laptop." Nooooooooooo you do not. You need to set up `wlp7s0b1`.

Comment: lol what a coincidence

Comment: see https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/

Answer (score 2):

Your wireless interface is `wlp7s0b1` not `wlan0`.

Comment: It is called "predictable interface names" and part of systemd.